# Not detecting Cookie on Vue Page

Tags: api, vue.js, go, cookies

Whenever the user make an API request I check if the session is valid

```
userCookie, err := r.Cookie("session-id")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        if strings.HasPrefix(r.URL.Path, "/login") {
            Login(w, r, db) //login and create session
        }
   } else {
     //Authenticate Session Then if Valid proceed to my APIs
   }
```

So when I consume an API directly on the browser's search bar it works because it detects the session cookie, but when I consume it on Vue/axios it doesn't detect the cookie and it gives me this error:

```
http: named cookie not present
exit status 1
```

When I create a session I set the cookie `Path: "/"` so the session cookie is also generated to my Vue page even though my server and front end have different ports. **So how can I make the server detect my session cookie on my Vue page?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to set [`withCredentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) to send cookies on CORS requests (and since you have a different port, it is treated as if it were a different server).

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  function(config) {
    // Do something before request is sent
    config.withCredentials = true;
    return config;
  },
  function(error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

or

```
axiox.get('/', { withCredentials: true })
```